# Using LINQ to select the last record in .NET Framework

Tags: linq

I need to query for the last record in a SQL database, utilizing LINQ.
The way I am doing it now takes two steps.  First, I get the ID value with a OrderByDescending.  then, I use the ID in another query to get the complete record set.

```
var model = _context.SystemViewModel.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID).Select(x => x.ID).FirstOrDefault();

if (ID > 0)
{
    ViewBag.user = from x in _context.SystemViewModel where x.ID == ID select x;
}
else
{
    ViewBag.user = from x in _context.SystemViewModel where x.ID == model select x;
}
```

IS there a way in LINQ to do this in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewBag.user = from x in _context.SystemViewModel where x.ID == (ID > 0 ? ID : model) select x;
```

You can use ?:operator
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Comment: This approach definitely removes the if statement block; well done.  Is there a way in LINQ to execute a single query that encompases both var model and ViewBag?